# KNNimputater of sklearn

Tags: sklearn-pandas

I want to use the knnimputer of sklearn for a dataset consists of multiple time series. each row in my data set related to a specific patient and columns related to the timestamps. it is not a multivariate time series but multiple univariate time series. there is also missing values and I want to try KNNimputer.

I want to know how should I pass my data to KNNimputer, should it be like patient* timestamps or like timestamps*patient? For me it is more relevant to find the nearest time series or patient to the time series with missing value, but I do know which order of the input will give me this.

I try both inputs, and surprisingly the result for timestamps*patient is better, but for me it is not relevant to see the patient as features and timestamps as samples.
This would be correct if KNNimputer find the nearest neightbor along features and not along samples but do not know if it is the case or not.